# Moving "MyDocuments" to D drive, did not free up space. Why is that?

Tags: windows-7, disk-space, my-documents

Somewhat related to my [previous question](https://superuser.com/questions/1341088/is-there-a-reason-to-keep-windows-primary-partition-drive-c-small).

So I ran out of space on my primary C drive (I'm using Windows 7), and choose to move all of "my documets" folder locatoin to d:\ drive, thought it would be free up 7GB of space that it was taking on C drive.

I ran windirstat before and after and it is exactly the same. Moving "My Documents" to D drive did not work. Am I missing anything.

Interesting if I try to move MyDocument location to default c:\ it throws error, not enough free space. What is wrong, is WinDirStat is reporting wrong but obviously I dont see any any free up space in my C drive after moving documents.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you use the "Move" button, or did you just manually edit the path?

Comment: go to my document location, click properties, location and edit path to d:, which prompted do you want to move these files and I said yes.

Comment: manually 'edit' the path and click ok. I now tried the 'move' button too, same result.

Comment: BUT there is no 'previous version' information in the folder. Out of frustration, I moved one folder (6.6GB) to "D:\my documents D" folder and even that did not have the affect [6.65GB folder - size](https://i.imgur.com/q1jlhif.png)

Comment: Are you sure D isn't simply an "alias" for a directory or for a virtual volume? Check on `diskmgmt.msc` how your partitions are arranged

Comment: @DDS it sure is a folder :) But I will double check

Comment: so if it's a folder, you discovered why moving data to it wwon't reduce used on C

Comment: That's why the question 1) Moving my document location didn't do anything 2) and moving individual big folder didn't do anything 3) and I can't move it back to C drive either.

Comment: So now I see 2.45GB free though, which should be 7GB  but at least I got some free space, changes were made hours ago. I was also able to change location to default [-6.65GB folder moved already]

Answer (score 1):

**I don't exactly know what happened**

- I first tried to changed location of 'my documents' folder by clicking properties->location and then 'edit locaton', change the path to D: While I did moved the files but size on drive c: did not change.
- Then I manually moved one big folder which was 6.65GB to d: but even that did not change anything. I restarted by PC, no effect. It was the same.
- I tried to change 'my documents' location to default but was not successful because there was simply no space

---

**Later**

After this I gave it a break, after about 2 hours, I tried to change the location of 'my documents' folder and yes this time it moved back. I check the size of drive c: and yes it had 2.45GB free. At least some success.

Then I ran windirstat and it still showed those big folder 6.65GB on C drive which in fact I moved by hand to d drive. Since I already had a copy of it on D (I verified), I deleted it from C drive and now I have about 8 GB of free space which I  needed to update visual studio.

Success but I don't know how? These are windows after all.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is to open Registry Editor and go to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\

- Shell Folders
- User Shell Folders

enter here the path you need

eg:

- Desktop = D:\Users\MyUserName\Desktop
- Personal = D:\Users\MyUserName\Documents

And after that manually move the files to the new location

Comment: Isn't that exactly what the settings in the Location tab do?

Comment: yes, but this is the manual procedure, in case the other fails